# Re-write dumbphone question, or ask new question?

Tags: discussion, questions

(Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I *believe* it is? Please feel free to tell me otherwise, and I can move/remove this question if necessary. Also, please feel free to add/remove tags - I haven't used Meta before, and I'm not sure what tags would go well here.)

Relating to my question [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/716/new-affordable-rugged-dumbphone-to-last-as-long-as-possible).

I'm tempted to re-write this question so that there's a much less strict set of preferences/requirements, essentially down to something like:

> **Needs**
>
> Dumbphone, strong/durable, good battery life, works on Australian 3g (or higher), should potentially last up to 10 years or more, under $50 AUD (though under $100 AUD acceptable).
>
> **Bonus points for**
>
> Handling being forgotten outside somewhere overnight, waterproof/water-resistant, the more recent the model was released the better.

With better formatting of course. Just trying to get my point across succinctly.

Are these two questions distinct enough to warrant being asked separately? Or should I just edit the question itself (and maybe add something like "(Updated)" to the title)?

If I should just edit the question itself, would the case be different if the question had received an answer/answers?

I'm leaning towards thinking I should just edit the question, but I get the nagging feeling that I'm missing something. E.g. if people would see the question pop up to the top of the list again, but not bother with it because they've already visited the question, seen the current requirements, and decided it's too hard to investigate? Is this even an issue? Maybe something else?...

In any case, I'll wait another day or two to see if any answers come in first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely edit your question. The edit doesn't make it dramatically different in any way, and seeing as there are no answers yet, feel free to edit it for clarity as many times as you need to.

Once it has an answer or two is when you should consider leaving it as it is and instead commenting on the answer to ask for more specificity. This is so that the answerers don't write up recommendations that will just become irrelevant after an edit. (Most people just go ahead and edit the question directly without regard to the current answers, though this usually doesn't cause any harm.)

Note for the future: no need for an edit to include anything like "(Updated)" in the title since your question will automatically appear at the top with the "modified" text under it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few scenarios in which it's perfectly fine to edit your question.

- If there are no answers.
  With no answers, you won't invalidate any answers by editing your question (which is generally why substantial edits are discouraged).
- If you're not changing the basic premise.
  If you don't change the basic thing you're asking about/for, then it's fine - again, you don't invalidate any answers.

It seems you're clear on both of these cases, so edit away!